# simulation (in Falstad's app) of thyristor using transistors fails

Tags: basic, thyristor, falstad

I am trying to simulate thyristor behavior with transistors PNP and NPN but it fails (is it a bug of app?). When lower switch is open(and was never closed) and upper closed then current flows through "thyristor" but it shouldn't. What is missing in this circuit?

[image]

circuit downloaded (serialized) below

```
$ 1 0.000005 10.20027730826997 50 5 50 5e-11
181 288 96 416 96 0 305.7461080505349 100 120 0.4 0.4
t 208 256 272 256 2 1 8.70252765514e-313 0 1 default
t 272 160 208 160 2 -1 -8.70252765514e-313 -1.377900477356e-312 1 default
r 128 256 192 256 0 1000
s 16 256 80 256 0 1 false
s 464 96 528 96 0 1 false
v 16 400 16 304 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
v 416 192 416 144 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
v 416 288 416 240 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
w 288 96 208 144 0
w 208 176 208 256 0
w 272 160 272 240 0
w 208 256 192 256 0
w 128 256 80 256 0
w 16 256 16 304 0
w 272 272 272 400 0
w 16 400 272 400 0
w 272 400 416 400 0
w 416 400 416 288 0
w 416 240 416 192 0
w 416 144 528 96 0
w 464 96 416 96 0
```

Comment: You haven't simulated a triac; you've simulated a thyristor or SCR.

Comment: you are right I made changes - it's a newbie mistake

Comment: It depends how the transistors are modeled - if they have no BE leakage and do have CE leakage they will turn on regardless of starting state. Try a BE switch on either transistor to force the off state, then open it and see if it stays off. You could put large resistors across BE on one or both transistors to drain off any CE leakage. Even stray junction capacitances on the transistors charging when the power goes on could draw enough current to turn them on initially

Comment: Are you aware that if the lower left switch was previously closed and then opened, current will continue to flow through the SCR? Is that what is confusing you? Maybe also having the switch open (in your sim) is asking a bit much. Try shorting the input out to 0 volts and see what happens instead.

Comment: When simulating a thyristor this way, it's probably best to have a resistor between the NPN's base and emitter. But circuitJS has a thyristor component anyway, doesn't it? Why not just use that?

Comment: @Andyaka lower switch was opened from the start, and current shouldn't flow but on simulation flows, that is what confuses me

Comment: @Hearth You are right. Since I am learning I would like to create this circuit, I like to tinker even with simple concept to fully understand it, it's better than just "memorising knowledge from book"

Comment: @quester That would be because the leakage current is enough to turn on the transistors; try what I suggested before of putting a resistor between the base and emitter.

Answer (score 0):

Your transistors have a tiny leakage current between the Collector and Base, which will cause them to turn on. Place a resistor between the Base and Emitter of each transistor to drain off the leakage current. A value of 10 GΩ is low enough for this simulation, but a much lower value (eg. 10 k) would be more practical.

Note that simulations never reproduce the real world exactly. A real transistor might stay turned off if the Base-Emitter leakage is high enough to soak up the Collector-Base leakage. But such a circuit will be very sensitive to noise, as well as critically dependent on individual transistor characteristics. Therefore you should always add a resistor to control the 'gate' sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Add a resistor between base and emitter of the npn.  With no resistor, both transistors are biased on.

[image]

With a biasing resistor added, the pnp is biased on, but the base on the npn is held to ground.  Almost any resistor can be used here up to 200Ω (voltage divider with 1kΩ).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the simulator starts, it doesn't 'know' the voltage at any node -- it builds a matrix of variables and ultimately solves it to determine each voltage.

The thyristor has two states -- on and off; both are valid. At the start, it is possible for the simulator to arrive at either of them.

Adding B-E resistors will help 'guide' it to the solution you expect, but it is not guaranteed in every case. If you also make the power supply ramp from 0 V to the final value, then the simulator can only arrive at one possible solution -- which is the one you want in this case.